# ngModel de Angular no me toma la fecha seleccionada en el datepicker de Materialize

Tags: javascript, angular, materialize

Actualmente trato de implementar materialize a un proyecto. Sin embargo a la hora de tomar el valor de fecha elegida a travez del datepicker y enviarlo, el valor de fecha no es enviado al revisar el objeto cuando lo imprimo.

HTML:

```
<input name="fecha" #fecha="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="producto.fecha" type="text" class="datepicker2">
```

Component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    $('.datepicker2').datepicker({
      format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
      disableWeekends: true,
      firstDay: 1,
      onSelect: (date) => {
        this.fec = date;
        console.log(this.fec);
       }
    });    }


   onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.producto);
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan tener una solución y me digan como aplicarlo.

Saludos.!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a mover el código del datepicker a la función de angular `ngAfterViewInit()`. Es posible que cuando llamas a jQuery en el `onInit()` el nodo `$('.datepicker2')` no se haya generado todavía en la página y por eso no lo puedes acceder.

Para debugearlo, prueba a asignar `$('.datepicker2')` a una variable y hacerle console.log. Es muy probable que te salga undefined